# Basic Wp_user_query not finding any users

Tags: wp-user-query

For some reason, the most basic wordpress user query i got from this generator

https://generatewp.com/wp_user_query/

is displaying that it has not found any users

```
    $args = array (
    );

    // The User Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { 
        //do stuff here
       }

   } else { 
   echo "no users found";
   //this is the error i keep getting. so this basic script is not finding any results
  }
```

am i missing something?

Comment: I think you need to explain, is it show your text "no users found" or what? please edit yours.

Comment: edited to clarfiy

Comment: Ok, so as @birgire answer and explain about your an empty array of query arguments, what you can say or do?

Answer (score 2):

> the most basic wordpress user query [...] is displaying that it has
>   not found any users

You're passing an empty array of query arguments and there's an explicit check for that in the `WP_User_Query` constructor:

```
 /**
  * PHP5 constructor.
  *
  * @since 3.1.0
  *
  * @param null|string|array $query Optional. The query variables.
  */
 public function __construct( $query = null ) {
      if ( ! empty( $query ) ) {
           $this->prepare_query( $query );
           $this->query();
     }
}
```

so that would explain why you get no results in your basic example.